# DotNetNuke ControlBar not showing

Tags: dotnetnuke

Windows Server 2008 R2

IIS 7.5

DNN 7.2.1

Application Pool - .NET Framework Version = v4.0

After fresh install I get the problem when ControlBar is showing like this in IE10:

[image]

and does not respond to any actions.

And Google Chrome shows the website like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking to see why your IIS site isn't serving up STATIC Files. Looks like your CSS and Images aren't loading.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the site is not running in Compatibility Mode or you didn't accidentally place the site on the Compatibility list.

You can also try hitting F12, going to the Network tab and refreshing the site.  This will let you see if any resources (css/js) aren't getting loaded (404).